# Preview a Text by selecting values of two spinners

Tags: android, android-spinner

In my application I used two spinners with the same values "max", "medium" and "low". I want to preview a Pre-typed Text on **Text View** when the button is clicked. for all 9 combinations.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: I add two spinners and a button for an activity. i need to open a new activity by selecting items from both and clicking the button..